# Bootstrap Foundation: On large screens the website positions two containers besides each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good evening,

I have a question regarding the Bootstrap 4.1 Grid. I built a normal website with multiple "containers" and "columns".

```html
<div class"container">
  <div class"row">
    <div class="col-12">
      CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class"container">
  <div class"row">
    <div class="col-12">
      CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On normal displays, this works perfectly fine as both containers are showed underneath each other.

But on very large screens the containers are besides each other.

How can I adjust my code, so that independently of the screen size, the containers are always showed below each other.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really reproduce your issue but you might be missing an equal sign in your classes.

```
class="container"
class="row"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing equals

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
     CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
  CONTENT
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry I forgot the equal signs. But this code was just an example to keep things simple.